# Will resetting a security token on sandbox affect production in Salesforce?

Tags: sandbox

I am trying to reset the sandbox token for Salesforce.

Will this action in anyway affect my production settings?

Comment: No. Changing your password or security token in a sandbox does not affect anything in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sandbox is different from your Production environment.